# jQuery isotope filtering is too slow

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery isotope plugin with filter to show about 70 items, with filtering option. I noticed that the page takes about 25 seconds to load, even if when it's loaded it works perfectly. Is there a way to prevent the page takes so long to load? I would be fine even wait 25 seconds, but with the rest of the page loaded, than wait so long with a blank page (which it seems that nothing is happening at all). Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to the problem?

Comment: yes but it's accessible only from my IP (the site is currently offline), that's why I didn't put it.

Comment: When going to the isotope site, where the plugin is hosted do you notice a slowness on the periodic table of element! because it isn't slow for everyone. But many things like ram and browser version amongst other things could cause unusual slowness...

Comment: I tried with several browsers, and I have 18 GB of RAM. The problem is that the page is blank when it's loading, because it waits the images and the plugin is loaded first, I would like it shows something even if isotope is loading all the effects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a loading gif image on the body first.

Just make sure you place it in the html or the style sheet before any of the javascript stuff happend you should have it loaded.

Comment: I saw that if I remove the script, the page takes the same time to load. So I need to view the page even if the DOM and the images are not loaded.